# unable to get property 'childnodes'

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying javascript to delete a textbox using checkbox. Here is the javascript:

```
 function deleteRowFromTable(tableID) {
    try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        alert(rowCount);
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];

            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if (rowCount <= 2) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
```

Here is my html

```
  <div class="col-md-4" style="overflow-x:auto;">

        <br>
<input class="col-md-3" type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRowFromTable('tableId3')">
        <br><br>
        <table class="col-md-6" id="tableId3">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>table 3</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <!--                    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"></td>
                                    <td><input name="name-1" id="name-1" value=""/></td>-->
            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>
```

Please advice why I am getting the error unable to get property 'childnodes' of undefined or null reference?

Comment: Your TR doesn't actually contain any cells?

Comment: I assume the TR you are referring to is the one where I commented out the checkbox right? I removed the initial checkbox because I have JS which should be able to manually add a checkbox

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
```

assumes that `row.cells[0]` will return an object. But if there are no cells in a row (the second row in your HTML, for instance, has no cells in it), it will return `undefined`. You can't read `.childNodes` of `undefined`.

Comment: I removed the initial checkbox because I have another JS that should be able to manually add a checkbox but after populating a check it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: @Newbph: Doesn't really change anything. Why are you getting the error? Because `row.cells[0]` isn't returning a cell object. So you need to look at why that is. If it's a valid thing your code may run into, you need to allow for it in your code.

Comment: Thanks! It's much better to learn this way. I seem have understood why im getting the error. It seems because of the extra <tr> that I had in my table.